# Agrupar Querys en un Stored Procedure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenos dias, 
Tengo un problema y no se como resolverlo, necesito realizar un reporte, el cual me solicitaron ciertas mediciones por MES.
lo que tengo es la Query de cada medición, pero no sé la forma de agrupar todas estas Querys mediante un SP, mas que ayuda, necesito saber como realizarlo, con que metodo, etc

**Querys:**

Compromisos por Mes:

```
Select COUNT(c.ID) as 'CantidadGenerada' ,MONTH(c.Com_FechaCreacion) as 'Mes' from Compromisos c
group by MONTH(c.Com_FechaCreacion)
```

Cantidad de asistentes:

```
select Count(Re.ID) as 'CantidadIntegrantes' from Rel_Reunion_Integrantes RE
inner join Reuniones R on
    R.ID=RE.Reu_ID
    group by MONTH(R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio)
```

Cantidad casos resueltos:

```
Select COUNT(c.ID) as 'CantidadResuelto' ,MONTH(c.Com_FechaTermino) as 'Mes' from Compromisos c
group by MONTH(c.Com_FechaTermino)
```

Total Horas por mes:

```
 select sum((datediff(minute, R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio, R.Reu_FechaCitaTermino))) AS 'DuracionReuniones',Month(Reu_FechaCitaInicio) as 'Mes'
 from Rel_Reunion_Integrantes RE
inner join Reuniones R on
    R.ID=RE.Reu_ID
    group by MONTH(R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio)
```

Cantidad Reuniones:

```
select COUNT(R.ID) as 'CantidadReuniones',MONTH(R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio) as 'Mes' from Reuniones R
    group by MONTH(R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio)
```

Resultado a obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y el SP que va a devolver? pq no puede devolver 5 querys distintas...

Comment: @gbianchi necesito obtener el resultado de estas 5 querys, una por celda agrupados por mes, como lo muestra la imagen que subi a la pregunta

Comment: ok, pero ese resultado no sale en SQL (que para colmo, no aclaraste sobre que motor). Ese resultado es el render de algun proceso desde algun lenguaje. Un SP devuelve un solo resultado.

Comment: Tu tercera consulta no tiene el `GROUP BY`....cuál es la columna que contiene el mes en este caso?

Comment: @Lamak se me fue ese detalle, las 5 querys van agrupadas por la columna de Mes

Comment: Entiendo que van agrupadas por mes, la pregunta es por el mes de qué columna de fecha

Comment: @Lamak mmm para cada caso hay una columna designada, las 5 Querys deben ser agrupadas por solo 1 columna de Fecha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viendo las query se me ocurre que puedes agrupar los set de resultados en una tabla en memoria y hacer un pivote desde esa tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
declare @Datos Table
(
  Tipo varchar(150),
  Cantidad int,
  Mes varchar(25)
)

SET LANGUAGE Spanish
-- Compromisos * mes
Insert into @Datos
Select 'CantidadGenerada', COUNT(c.ID) ,datename(mm ,c.Com_FechaCreacion) from Compromisos c
group by c.Com_FechaCreacion

--Cantidad de asistentes
Insert into @Datos
select 'CantidadIntegrantes', Count(Re.ID), datename(mm ,R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio) from Rel_Reunion_Integrantes RE
inner join Reuniones R on
    R.ID=RE.Reu_ID
    group by R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio

--Cantidad casos resueltos
Insert into @Datos
Select 'CantidadResuelto', COUNT(c.ID)  ,datename(mm ,c.Com_FechaTermino) from Compromisos c
group by c.Com_FechaTermino

--Horas por mes
Insert into @Datos
 select 'DuracionReuniones', sum((datediff(minute, R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio, R.Reu_FechaCitaTermino))), datename(mm ,Reu_FechaCitaInicio) 
 from Rel_Reunion_Integrantes RE
inner join Reuniones R on
    R.ID=RE.Reu_ID
    group by R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio
-- Cantidad de reuniones
Insert into @Datos
select 'CantidadReuniones', COUNT(R.ID) ,datename(mm ,R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio) from Reuniones R
    group by R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio

Select Tipo,
isnull([Enero], 0) as Enero,
isnull([Febrero], 0) as Febrero,
isnull([Marzo], 0) as Marzo,
isnull([Abril], 0) as Abril,
isnull([Mayo], 0) as Mayo,
isnull([Junio], 0) as Junio,
isnull([Julio], 0) as Julio,
isnull([Agosto], 0) as Agosto,
isnull([Septiembre], 0) as Septiembre,
isnull([Octubre], 0) as Octubre,
isnull([Noviembre], 0) as Noviembre,
isnull([Diciembre], 0) as Diciembre
from (
    Select Tipo, Cantidad, Mes
    from @Datos
) as Pvt
Pivot
(
    SUM(Cantidad)
    For Mes in ([Enero], [Febrero], [Marzo], [Abril], [Mayo], [Junio],
        [Julio], [Agosto], [Septiembre], [Octubre], [Noviembre], [Diciembre])
) as TablaPivoteada
```

Alguien con mas experiencia puede sugerir algo mas elegante, pero para efectos de tu imagen de referencia te da el resultado, aun habria que pulir los resultados que regresen nulo, pero la idea basica esta ahi

[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e06fd/5/0]Link a SqlFiddel[1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e06fd/5/0)

> **Nota:** El fiddle esta basado en resultados que deberian de regresar tus consultas, y como menciona Lamak en su respuesta si las consultas no limitan el año la consulta sumara los datos de todos los meses de años diferentes

Comment: Oh muchas gracias! se comprende el metodo de dar con la solucion, pero me genera un error, al insertar los datos a la tabla @Datos (Un error por cada Insert),
"Column 'Reuniones.Reu_FechaCitaInicio' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: @ArielIgnacio hay que quitar el month() en los group by, ya actualice la respuesta saludos

Comment: oh Muchisimas gracias! es justo lo que necesitaba :D

Answer (score 2):

Ok, esto es bastante simple, si bien algo repetitivo. Basta con hacer una serie de joins entre tus consultas:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(q1.Mes,q2.Mes,q3.Mes,q4.Mes,q5.Mes) Mes,
        ISNULL(q1.CantidadGenerada,0) CantidadGenerada,
        ISNULL(q2.CantidadIntegrantes,0) CantidadIntegrantes,
        ISNULL(q3.CantidadResuelto,0) CantidadResuelto,
        ISNULL(q4.DuracionReuniones,0) DuracionReuniones,
        ISNULL(q5.CantidadReuniones,0) CantidadReuniones
FROM (  SELECT  MONTH(c.Com_FechaCreacion) Mes
                COUNT(c.ID) CantidadGenerada
        FROM Compromisos c
        GROUP BY MONTH(c.Com_FechaCreacion)) q1
FULL JOIN ( SELECT  MONTH(R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio) Mes,
                    COUNT(Re.ID) CantidadIntegrantes 
            FROM Rel_Reunion_Integrantes RE
            INNER JOIN Reuniones R 
                ON R.ID = RE.Reu_ID
            GROUP BY MONTH(R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio)) q2
    ON q1.Mes = q2.Mes
FULL JOIN ( SELECT  COUNT(c.ID) CantidadResuelto,
                    MONTH(c.Com_FechaTermino) Mes
            FROM Compromisos c
            GROUP BY MONTH(c.Com_FechaTermino)) q3
    ON COALESCE(q1.Mes,q2.Mes) = q3.Mes
FULL JOIN ( SELECT  SUM((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio, R.Reu_FechaCitaTermino))) DuracionReuniones,
                    MONTH(Reu_FechaCitaInicio) Mes
            FROM Rel_Reunion_Integrantes RE
            INNER JOIN Reuniones R 
                ON R.ID = RE.Reu_ID
            GROUP BY MONTH(R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio)) q4
    ON COALESCE(q1.Mes,q2.Mes,q3.Mes) = q4.Mes
FULL JOIN ( SELECT  COUNT(R.ID) CantidadReuniones,
                    MONTH(R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio) Mes
            FROM Reuniones R
            GROUP BY MONTH(R.Reu_FechaCitaInicio)) q5
    ON COALESCE(q1.Mes,q2.Mes,q3.Mes,q4.Mes) = q5.Mes
;
```

Sí te debo recordar que esto sería válido si las consultas son para un año en particular, sino se te juntarán meses de años diferentes.